# Download file from google drive using google-api-services-drive:v3

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

i just can't manage to download file from google drive, i have just created. I can get the webContentLink. If i access this via browser, i can download file, but i can't download the same file via my app...i read almost every documentation about google drive, but i could not find any way to download file to my storage.

Here i get the link for the file...i can get what ever i want like this

```
downloadLink = m.getAlternateLink();
downloadLink = m.getEmbedLink();
downloadLink = m.getWebContentLink();
downloadLink = m.getWebViewLink();
```

or every other parameter like DriveId...

Here is my code to get it the infos for file on Drive:

```
Query query2 = new Query.Builder()
     .addFilter(Filters.and(Filters.eq(
     SearchableField.TITLE, "locations.csv"),
     Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)))
                                .build();
     Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query2)
     .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
       if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
         System.out.println("File does not exists");
           } else {
             for(Metadata m : result.getMetadataBuffer()) {
             if (m.getTitle().equals("locations.csv")) {
              downloadLink = m.getWebContentLink();
              }
           }
        }
      }
   });
```

In this folder, there is only one file located, i am sure. So i just need a way to get this one file downloaded in background to sd card or better specific folder.

Any help is welcome! Thanks.

**MY SOLUTION**

On click somewhere in code

```
driveFileMy.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                    .setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);
```

then i am doing this:

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>  contentsOpenedCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    // display an error saying file can't be opened
                    return;
                }
                // DriveContents object contains pointers
                // to the actual byte stream
                DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();
                InputStream inputStream = contents.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(filelocation);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }

                    out.flush();
                    inputStream.close();
                    out.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```

String filelocation is the location of output file, where it should be saved. Thanks everyone :)!

Comment: If your downloadLink has a link that you can use to download via browser it is not only open that link with an InputStream and save the content in your sd card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drive API has a [full guide on working with file contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files), i.e., getting a direct `InputStream` of the file.

Given a `DriveFile`, you open it with

```
DriveFile file = ...
file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
    .setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);
```

Using a `ResultCallback` that looks like:

```
ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> contentsOpenedCallback =
    new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
      // display an error saying file can't be opened
      return;
    }
    // DriveContents object contains pointers
    // to the actual byte stream
    DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();
  }
};
```

You can then read from the `InputStream` via `contents.getInputStream()`, writing it out to local file if you'd like.

Keep in mind that since Google Drive **already keeps a local copy** once you've opened a file, if you only need the contents within your app, it is better to use the `InputStream` directly rather than save it to yet another local file (doubling the storage space needed).

Comment: my bad, how could i miss this part...never worked with InputStream but i will try to figure it out. I need the local copy in specific folder so my app can access it. Thanks, i will post a code if i will get it to work.

Comment: Your app is accessing the byte-for-byte identical `InputStream` already, but okay. Best of luck!